# Read file letter by letter and transfer the result to another file in python

Tags: python-3.x, file

I want to read this file letter by letter and transfer the result to another file.

This is my Try, but it did not work In transferring the result to the file (f2)

```
with open("Text.txt") as f:
while True:
    letter = f.read(1)
    with open("Output.txt",'w') as f2:
        f2.write(letter)
    print (" The letter is :", letter)# This just for try if work or not ...and his print the result in consol
    if not letter:
        print ("End Of File")
        break

    f2.close()
```

the file Text.txt have text of code source

Please help me and thank you for your support.

Comment: You are overwriting the file with each iteration. open with `'a'` instead of `'w'`. Also if you use `with` you don't need to `close` the file

Comment: A better loop construct would be `for char in iter(lambda: f.read(1), ''):`

Comment: mr  Tomerikoo    I made the edit 'a' and remove  'f2.close()' but it just prints the text in Text.txt  complete and not the result

Comment: **mr N Chauhan**  I'm Try u edit and the resulte is the same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, after several failed try, I solved it

```
with open("Text.txt",'r') as f:
letter = ""
l = []
while True:
    letter = f.read(1)
    l.append(letter)
    f2 = open("Output.txt",'w')

    f2.write(str(' '.join(l)))
    print (" The letter is :", letter)
    if not letter:
        print ("End Of File")
        break
```

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me ^_^

Comment: The idea I used was to put each letter in a list and then remove the parentheses .